# Display image from SQL DB in QLabel

Tags: python, sql-server, pyqt

The database stores images in varbinary format. I am getting data like this b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00\xff\xe1\x00ZExif\x... I can save them if I use the code

```
    photo_path = r'C:\1' + '\\'
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-8EKCG28\RUSGUARD;DATABASE=RUSGUARDDB;UID=sa;PWD=123')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT Photo FROM [RusGuardDB].[dbo].[EmployeePhoto]")
    retrieved_bytes = cursor.execute("SELECT Photo FROM [RusGuardDB].[dbo].[EmployeePhoto]").fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    sum = numpy.array(retrieved_bytes)
    for a in range(len(sum)):
        sum1 = sum[a]
        with open(photo_path + 'new' + str(a) + '.jpg', 'wb') as new_jpg:
            new_jpg.write(sum1)
```

I don't want to save pictures, i want show them directly in QLabel. How can i do this?

Comment: Hopefully those *aren't* your real credentials, but the connection string implies your application is using the `sa` account; it *really* should not be.

Comment: This is a test SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finded solution for my problem.

```
retrieved_bytes = cursor.execute("SELECT Photo FROM [RusGuardDB].[dbo].[EmployeePhoto]").fetchone()
for row in retrieved_bytes:
            row_to_list = [elem for elem in row]
        pixmap = QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(bytearray(row_to_list))
        self.label1.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Answer (score -1):

From the look of the header (`b'\xff\xd8`), those seem to be standard jpeg images as raw data.

You can show them by using [`loadFromData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#loadFromData-1), Qt is smart enough to recognize the file format from its contents, as long as the data is not corrupted.
Note that that function returns a bool stating if loading was successful or not, so you first need to create the instance, and *then* call the function.

```
    for result in retrieved_bytes:
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        if pixmap.loadFromData(result):
            label = QLabel(pixmap=pixmap)
            someLayout.addWidget(label)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand you. can you write in more detail? For GUI i use Qt Designer, and import ui file

Comment: You said that you want to show it directly in a label, that's what is done in my code. If you already have a label and want to set a pixmap for it, then just use `self.yourLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)`.

Comment: i receive error. setPixmap(self, QPixmap): argument 1 has unexpected type 'pyodbc.Row'

Comment: Then you used the wrong argument, check your syntax and ensure that the argument of `setPixmap` is the QPixmap instance you created.

Comment: Yes. All right. Maybe pyodbc gived wrong format? In error I see pyodbc.Row Row this is a list. Maybe need convert?

Comment: No, the point is that if you get that error it means that the argument you're using is **not** a QPixmap instance; even if the data wasn't valid, you should *not* get that error if you correctly used a QPixmap instance. I suggest you to put that portion of your current code on a gist or pastebin so that we can check what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't do that now. I left the office. I can posting code later or tomorrow. Thank you for help